# Problem with fetching a user from Firebase with an id that's a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a react app and I'm google firebase.

I made a collection of users and each user whose document ids are the user's emails.

First I get the authUser and there I get the email of my current user and when I console log it it's fine.
I set that email with useState:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const listen = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      setAuthUser(user);
      setEmail(user.email);
    } else {
      setAuthUser(null);
    }
  });

  return () => {
    listen();
  };
}, []);
```

Then when I try to fetch the document data I use this code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getDoc(doc(db, "users", "name.surname@gmail.com"))
    .then(docSnap => {
      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        setData(docSnap.data());
        console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
      } else {
        console.log("No such document exists");
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Error fetching document:", error);
    });
}, []);
```

This way I get all the data and it works just fine.

But of course I don't want to but the static email in getDoc. Instead I want to put the email that I got for that current user.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getDoc(doc(db, "users", email))
    .then(docSnap => {
      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        setData(docSnap.data());
        console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
      } else {
        console.log("No such document exists");
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Error fetching document:", error);
    });
}, [email]);
```

But this way I get an error saying:

> Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1.
> FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1.

The email is correct 100% and I don't know what the problem is anymore.

This is the path to my document from firebase (I copied it):
/users/"name.surname@gmail.com"

Can someone please help me?

I tried putting it the quotes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getDoc(doc(db, "users", `"${email}"`))
    .then(docSnap => {
      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        setData(docSnap.data());
        console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
      } else {
        console.log("No such document exists");
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Error fetching document:", error);
    });
}, [email]);
```

I also tried making another variable, for example:

```
const id= `"${email}"`

useEffect(() => {
  getDoc(doc(db, "users", id))
    .then(docSnap => {
      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        setData(docSnap.data());
        console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
      } else {
        console.log("No such document exists");
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Error fetching document:", error);
    });
}, [id]);
```

But nothing seems to work, only the static email.

Comment: In your third code sample it sounds like `email` doesn't have a value. You'll want to get for that, as there's nothing to load if you don't have an email address. So `if (email) { getDoc.... }`.

Comment: Print the value of `email` immediate before you use it with getDoc.  What does it contain? Don't do any special quoting with it - just use the plain value.

Comment: As I said I console log the email and it contains the correct value even immediately before using it in getDoc but the error still remains.